# Is there a limit to the amount of elements in a Vector in Java?

Tags: java

Does the Vector class of Java have a limit to the amount of elements it can store? I know it automatically grows and should be able to store an arbitrary amount of elements, however are there any limitations that limit the amount of elements you can actually store? Other than the most obvious limitation like running out of memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two limits:

- the amount of memory
- the max integer value ([`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)), since elements in the underlying array are indexed by an integer index

Side note: if you plan to use Vector, then don't. Use ArrayList instead, which is not synchronized and fits better with the rest of the Collections framework.

Answer (score 5):

Since the `size()` of a `Vector` is an `int`, which is a 32-bit signed integer, the maximum number of elements is 2**31-1 or roughly 2.1 billion elements.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, unless you're using Java 1.1 you should *usually* use `ArrayList<E>` rather than `Vector`. However, both will have the same limitations.

Basically, they're backed by an array and have internal `int` values for the current "real" length. So based on that, you won't be able to store more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` entries. However, it's very likely that you'll run out of memory before you get to this point anyway.

In fact, the implementation of `ArrayList` I'm looking at has a slightly smaller limit anyway, imposed internally:

```
/**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate.
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

Comment: The code we're using dates back to 2002 (and some specific java version I don't know which), that explains why it uses Vector rather than ArrayList<E>

Comment: @JoostvanDoorn: Well Java 2 introduced `ArrayList` back in 1998... unless you *need* the extra synchronization provided by `Vector`, now would be a good time to update the code to the now-preferred `ArrayList`...

Comment: I have no influence on the code used, as it is used in a class on software engineering at my University. The code is pretty bad, but there is no money to rewrite it so I have heard. This does not only concern the use of Vector ;)